# Setting NULL to reactive when button is clicked

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I need to set NULL to `reactive` when a button is clicked. In my example below 'data' (as module parameter) is passed as reactive from other module. Now, I want to click button and set NULL to `reactiveExpr`. The way I'm doing it here is not working. I don't need set NULL to `reactive` base on any condition, just by clicking the button.

```
mod_ui <- function(id){ 
  ns <- NS(id)

  actionButton(ns("btn"), "Click me")

}

mod_server <- function(id, data){ 
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session) { 

  ns <- NS(id)

  reactiveExpr <- reactive(data())

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    reactiveExpr(NULL) 
})

# some more code...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a reactive conductor (`reactive`), use a reactive value:

```
  reactiveExpr <- reactiveVal()

  observe({
    reactiveExpr(data())
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    reactiveExpr(NULL) 
  })
```